# Datagrid for nested endpoints in react-admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am trying to understand what the right approach would be to address nested endpoints, let's assume I have a many to many `books` and `authors` relationship, and an API which exposes `api/authors`, `api/books`, and `api/authors/{id}/books`. This is a common design pattern.

The CRUD on `api/authors` works beautifully in react-admin. However,  under the authors `<Show>` I want to show a `<Datagrid>` of all the books with pagination and sorting, which my api makes available under `api/authors/{id}/books`.

What is the right approach to make a datagrid of such a nested endpoint?

I've looked into the `<ReferenceManyField>` which works well in the one to many context but doesn't allow accessing nested endpoints, only filtering an endpoint.

Ideally I would want something that is along the lines of:

```
<Show {...props}>
    <TabbedShowLayout>
        <Tab label="Books">
            <NestedResourceField reference="books" nestedResource={`authors/${props.record.id}/books`} pagination={<Pagination/>} >
                <Datagrid>
                    <TextField source="name" />
                </Datagrid>
            </NestedResourceField>
        </Tab>
    </TabbedShowLayout>
</Show>
```

Note that `<NestedResourceField>` is a hypothetical component which would have a behavior very similar to [`<ReferenceManyField>`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#referencemanyfield) but would accept a nested endpoint under `nestedResource` instead of `target`.

I am struggling to understand what the design strategy should be for the hypothetical `<NestedResourceField>` in order to re-use as much of the react-admin framework as possible.

It would be straightforward to "manually" do the fetch myself and list the content but then I would lose all the pagination, filtering, sorting, etc... that comes with react-admin and the fact that `books` is an already defined resource.

My question is similar to these unanswered questions:

[custom routes in react-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51525116/custom-routes-in-react-admin)

[custom path for resource route in react-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585643/custom-path-for-resource-route-in-react-admin)

## Edit

Turns out an almost identical question which I had not found previously was posted here:
[Support for resource nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255057/support-for-resource-nesting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I decided to solve this with a hack in the dataProvider.

Keeping with the above example and using the stock [`ReferenceManyField`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#referencemanyfield):

```
<Show {...props}>
    <TabbedShowLayout>
        <Tab label="Books">
            <ReferenceManyField reference="books" target="_nested_authors_id" pagination={<Pagination/>} >
                <Datagrid>
                    <TextField source="name" />
                </Datagrid>
            </ReferenceManyField>
        </Tab>
    </TabbedShowLayout>
</Show>
```

I then modified my dataProvider, which is a fork of [ra-jsonapi-client](https://github.com/henvo/ra-jsonapi-client). 
I changed `index.js`  under the `case GET_MANY_REFERENCE` from this:

```
      // Add the reference id to the filter params.
      query[`filter[${params.target}]`] = params.id;

      url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
```

to this:

```
      // Add the reference id to the filter params.
      let refResource;
      const match = /_nested_(.*)_id/g.exec(params.target);
      if (match != null) {
        refResource = `${match[1]}/${params.id}/${resource}`;
      } else {
        query[`filter[${params.target}]`] = params.id;
        refResource = resource;
      }

      url = `${apiUrl}/${refResource}?${stringify(query)}`;
```

So basically I just remap the parameters to the url for the special case where the `target` matches a hard coded regex.

`ReferenceManyField` would normally have caused the dataProvider to call `api/books?filter[_nested_authors_id]=1` and this modification makes the dataProvider call `api/authors/1/books` instead. It is transparent to react-admin.

Not elegant but it works and doesn't seem to break anything on the front end.

Comment: Nice solution @vchev005. Is this still your preferred way to handle nested resources such as `api/authors/{id}/books`? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try using ArrayField component:

```
<Show {...props}>
    <TabbedShowLayout>
        <Tab label="Books">
            <ArrayField source="books" label="">
              <Datagrid>
                 <TextField source="name" />
              </Datagrid>
            </ArrayField>
        </Tab>
    </TabbedShowLayout>
</Show>
```

Where books is your nested resource field. In your "author" end point you should include books.